# Does the "rule of three" refer to the class type or clients that use the class type, or both?

Tags: c++

Say I am using vector as a client for a data field in another class.  Do I have to invoke special implementations for the assignment operator, destructor, and constructor for vector in that class?  Or is the "rule of three" referring to only the definitions for the client class type?

Comment: `std::vector` observes the Rule of Five so that you don't have to. If your class doesn't have to personally manage any resources it can and should implement the Rule of Zero. [Documentation on the Rules of Three, Five and Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: @user4581301 Excellent, thank you.

Comment: Side note: Do as `vector` does. One of your resource management goals in C++ is to manage the resource (Rule of Three/Five) as close to the resource as possible so that other classes don't even have to know the resource exists and can simply deal with your management class.

Comment: @user4581301 I'd express it as a hierarchy: if possible do as `int` does, otherwise if possible do as `std::vector` does, and finally otherwise do as `std::unique_ptr` does.